# Converting CHAR Primary Key to INT in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, char, type-conversion, mariadb

I have a table that uses `CHAR` as the primary key for customers. I am attempting to load this table into a schema such that the primary key should be an `INT`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` char(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES ('99944'),('99946'),('99976'),('A0014'),('A0049'),('A0124'),('C01AH'),('C01AQ'),('C01AW'),('C01AX'),('C01AY'),('C01AZ');
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88797b/2)

I have attempted variations on `select cast(customer_id AS UNSIGNED) FROM customers;` but only get back 0s  for the non-int rows. How do I cast the  non-int rows into a consistent `INT` result?

The ideal result would look like this:
For customer IDs that are solely integers, leave them alone.
For customer IDs that contain any letter, replace everything in the ID with a unique numerical identifier.

Expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers;

`customer_id`
-------
99944
99946
99976
13871911
13871912
13871913
13872128
13872229
13872293
13872505
13872512
13872561
```

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: is it always the first character that is the non-numeric? Do these IDs currently map to another table so a consistent transform is required?

Comment: No. A first character can be numeric or non-numeric. These IDs will map to another table, so consistency is required. For numeric IDs, leave as is. For non-numeric IDs, return a consistent result -- e.g., substitute the decimal ASCII codes for the non-numeric characters.

Comment: I advice you to make a expected result as formatted data.  How to do that you can read here [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I assume you have more tables which uses the `customer_id` in the columns?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hey @RaymondNijland... I was starting to like your solution !

Comment: @3C41DC which version of MySQL are you using ?

Comment: I'm running MariaDB 10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMB did give me a other idea. 
Using the `HEX()` and `CONV(.., 16, 10)` to convert from hexadecimals into decimales

**Query**

```
SELECT
   customers.customer_id
 , CASE 
    WHEN (customers.customer_id >> 0) > 0
    THEN customers.customer_id >> 0
    ELSE
     CONV(HEX(customers.customer_id), 16, 10)
    END
   AS customer_id_int
FROM 
 customers;
```

**Result**

```
| customer_id | customer_id_int |
| ----------- | --------------- |
| 99944       | 99944           |
| 99946       | 99946           |
| 99976       | 99976           |
| A0014       | 279981338932    |
| A0049       | 279981339705    |
| A0124       | 279981404724    |
| C01AH       | 288571343176    |
| C01AQ       | 288571343185    |
| C01AW       | 288571343191    |
| C01AX       | 288571343192    |
| C01AY       | 288571343193    |
| C01AZ       | 288571343194    |
```

**p.s**
It might be generating a to large int you need to use a `BIGINT` datatype. 
see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/0)

**Updated**

A other method to generate smaller int's (`UNSIGNED INT`) which uses a "SQL number generator", `SUBSTRING()`, `ORD()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

**Query**

```
    SELECT 
       customers.customer_id
     CASE 
       WHEN customers.customer_id >> 1 > 0
       THEN customers.customer_id 
       ELSE
         GROUP_CONCAT(
           CASE
             WHEN SUBSTRING(customers.customer_id, number_generator.number, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
             THEN SUBSTRING(customers.customer_id, number_generator.number, 1) >> 1
             ELSE ORD(SUBSTRING(customers.customer_id, number_generator.number, 1))
           END
           ORDER BY 
             number_generator.number ASC
           SEPARATOR ''
         )                            
     END                            
   ) AS customer_id_int                  
    FROM (
      SELECT 
       record_1.number
      FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
      ) AS record_1   
    ) AS number_generator
    CROSS JOIN
     customers
    GROUP BY 
     customers.customer_id
    ORDER BY 
     customers.customer_id ASC
```

**Result**

```
| customer_id | customer_id_int |
| ----------- | --------------- |
| 99944       | 99944           |
| 99946       | 99946           |
| 99976       | 99976           |
| A0014       | 650002          |
| A0049       | 650024          |
| A0124       | 650012          |
| C01AH       | 67006572        |
| C01AQ       | 67006581        |
| C01AW       | 67006587        |
| C01AX       | 67006588        |
| C01AY       | 67006589        |
| C01AZ       | 67006590        |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/6)

Comment: I knew you were up to something ! +1 since this solution meets the requirement and also does provide an alternative for versions of MySQL / MariaDB that do not support `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: @GMB and @3C41DC take a look into mine other `REGEXP_REPLACE` replacing method which i updated into mine answer works on both MySQL / MariaDB.. it kind off works the same as GMB's `REGEXP_REPLACE` query method. besides it generate a much smaller int which fits in a `UNSIGNED INT` datatype

Answer (score 2):

With Maria DB >= 10.0.5, here is a solution to turn a string primary key to an integer primary key in a predictable manner :

```
SELECT 
    customer_id old_id,
    CAST(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(customer_id, '([^0-9])', ORD('$1')) 
        AS UNSIGNED
    ) new_id
FROM customers;
```

[`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) captures non-numeric characters (anywhere in the string) and [`ORD()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/ord/) turns each of them into its ordinal (numerical) represtation.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e91851cb6b127a915bb5682111642053)** :

```
old_id |   new_id
:----- | -------:
99944  |    99944
9Z946  |   936946
A9CZ6  | 36936366
A0C14  |  3603614
0ABC0  |  3636360
```

Comment: No.  That can lead to dups.  Customer '41410' and 'AA0' will both be '41410'.

Comment: @RickJames : ah yes, you are right. I modified my answer to not mention uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Using MySQL 8.0 `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
select cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(customer_id,'[^0-9]','') AS UNSIGNED) FROM customers;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=683b23f47df4765ec9447613fe2d5019)**

Comment: Sorry, I updated the requirements. Running this on the IDs C01AH
C01AQ
C01AW
C01AX
C01AY
C01AZ all return a converted ID of 1.